# CAKeyframeAnimation rotation don't draw real shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, shadow, cakeyframeanimation

I want to rotate an UIImageView with CAKeyframeAnimation. The problem is that the shadow rotates with the object, making a non-real effect... [The shadow must remain under the image, not rotating around it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzaiI.png)

This is my code. Very simple:

```
    let imagen:UIImageView = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named: "material6.png"))

    self.view.addSubview(imagen)

    imagen.center = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)

    imagen.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75
    imagen.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 15)

    //Animación del ángulo
    let animacionAngulo = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")

    var valoresAngulo = [NSNumber]()
    let degrees:Float = 360
    let radians = degrees * Float.pi / Float(180.0)

    valoresAngulo.append(NSNumber(value: 0))
    valoresAngulo.append(NSNumber(value: radians))

    animacionAngulo.values = valoresAngulo

    //Permite añadir varias animaciones y gestionarlas a la vez
    animacionAngulo.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    animacionAngulo.duration = 2.0

    imagen.layer.add(animacionAngulo, forKey: nil)
```

Any solution?

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it achieves your desired effect.

Comment: Yes, it's perfect... I have to change the code a little because my question was only a part of the total animation (position, shadowOffset, size...), but my problem was about the shadow orientation. So, solved! Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the shadow is rotating along with the image. You can solve it by adding an `UIView` with same dimensions of your `UIImageView` below your `UIImageView`. If you add shadow to your `UIView` instead of `UIImageView`, you can achieve the desired effect in this case.

```
let imagen:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
imagen.center = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
imagen.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

let belowView: UIView = UIView(frame: imagen.frame)
belowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
belowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75
belowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 15)
self.view.addSubview(belowView)

self.view.addSubview(imagen)

    //Animación del ángulo
let animacionAngulo = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")

var valoresAngulo = [NSNumber]()
let degrees:Float = 360
let radians = degrees * Float.pi / Float(180.0)

valoresAngulo.append(NSNumber(value: 0))
valoresAngulo.append(NSNumber(value: radians))

animacionAngulo.values = valoresAngulo

    //Permite añadir varias animaciones y gestionarlas a la vez
animacionAngulo.repeatCount = Float.infinity
animacionAngulo.duration = 2.0

imagen.layer.add(animacionAngulo, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I've been fighting against this for days... Looking for a solution and I haven't found it... You save my week! ;)